# logical error at x=2 and n=4 while printing 1+x+x2 /2! + x3 /3! +… n terms

Tags: c++

limitations :

- cant use function for factorial,
- cant use while/do while loop.

aim :
to print 1+x+x2 /2! + x3 /3! +… n terms

problem :
at x=2 and n=4 input, output is 5.6667 which should be 6.3333

- outputs for n=0,1,2,3 are correct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x, n, sum = 0;
    cout << "ENTER x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "ENTER n: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0, fac = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            fac *= j;

        sum += pow(x, i) / fac;
    }

    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *cant use while/do while loop* sounds a lot like your class may have recently covered recursion.

Comment: I don't see a clear problem description here.

Comment: @KenWhite at x=2 and n=4 input, output is 5.6667 which should be 6.3333

Comment: you never define `fac`

Comment: @user4581301 am expected to use for loop for finding factorial and that is a non issue for me

Comment: @ti7 fac is in the for loop for scoping purposes

Comment: Tactical note: Memorize your factorial computations so you don't have to repeat all of the previous work on each iteration.

Comment: @KenWhite please read the for loop declaration once again `for (int i = 0, fac = 1; i < n; i++)
`

Comment: `fac` is initialized to `1` once, at the start of the loop, not on every iteration through the loop (just like `i` is only initialized to 0 once). It's not `1!` then `2!` then `3!` - it's `1!` then `1!*2!` then `1!*2!*3!`

Comment: This is a program small enough that you can step through it line by line in the debugger. Watch the value of `fac` before the inner `for` loop, when `i` is 3.

Comment: Stack Overflow usage note: When you know the inputs that trigger the error, don't ask for inputs. Hardcode them. Eg: `float x = 2, n = 4, sum = 0;` This makes it easier for you (and us) to run the program over and over in a debugger until you (or we) spot the mistake.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I see my mistake. What should I correct ?

Comment: Your code. I suppose I don't understand the question.

Comment: Anyway, consider something like this instead; `float m = 1; for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { sum += m; m *= x/i; }` Proof of correctness is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to place `fac = 1;` before second loop, then your code gives correct answer. Also `n` should be `int`, not `float`.

Corrected code:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/TjfYzoqfv)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    float x, sum = 0;
    cout << "ENTER x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "ENTER n: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0, fac = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        fac = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            fac *= j;

        sum += pow(x, i) / fac;
    }

    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2 4
```

Output:

```
6.33333
```

Also don't forget that with larger `n` factorial will overflow `int`, so better to make `fac` variable float or double, i.e. instead of `int fac;` do `double fac;`, that's enough to overcome overflow.

It is obvious that you can make computation faster by incorporating recursive formula of each term computation instead of computing full `pow()` and Factorial on each iteration.

My version of optimized code with recursive formula is following:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/T7Y3Kx8vb)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    float x, term = 1, sum = 0;
    cout << "ENTER x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "ENTER n: ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n >= 1)
        sum = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        term *= x / i;
        sum += term;
    }

    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2 4
```

Output:

```
6.33333
```